# how to create UISelectItems from a Database

Tags: database, jsf-2, custom-component

We are in the need of populating UISelectOne- and UISelectMany-Components with SeletItems from a database. Instead of subclassing I decided to create a Child-Component element which is able to provide the SelectItems. This way we dont have to introduce new components for this behavior.

But I cant see whats the best way to do this. At first I thought I just need a TagHandler but it seems that idea was a dead end. I tried to create SelectItems within the apply-method but I dont know how to add the items to the component.

Is there another way. Do I have to create a component instead of a TagHandler?

I might be on the wrong path anyway: as mentioned above, I tried to add the items to the component, but shouldnt this be done by the component-tree automatically.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, how exactly is `<f:selectItems>` in combination with some application wide `#{data}` managed bean insufficient?

Comment: because then we need to provide the code in each bean using some helpermethod. The idea is that we just provide a logical key from the database to the tag and this is then added automatically.

Comment: I fail to see/understand why "in each bean" is necessary. The `<f:selectItems value>` doesn't necessarily need to refer the same managed bean as where the `value` of the parent select component points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but I dont know how to add the items to the component*

Just add it as child of the parent component which is already supplied as argument of [`apply()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletHandler.html#apply%28javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29).

```
parent.getChildren().add(selectItems);
```

Comment: doh! Right...I will just try that out. I think my mistake was that I was working with the class SelectItem, instead of UISelectItem. I still dont know what the difference really is.

Comment: The `SelectItem` is the model object representing a single select item (with value and label and so on). The `UISelectItem` represents the option component autogenerated by `<f:selectItem>` (and the `UISelectItems` represents the option components autogenerated by `<f:selectItems>`).